# jQuery UI: button to open link in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following code,

```
var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
$("#leaving-dialog").dialog({
    buttons: {
        "No, I want to stay here": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Yes, that's okay": function () {
            window.location.href = targetUrl;
        }
    }
});
```

which basically makes one of the buttons send the user somewhere. What I want it to do, is open the link in a new window or tab and then close the modal (as they will still have the original page open).

Any idea how I could resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `window.open(targetUrl);` instead of `window.location.href`, and add the line to `close` the dialog after that.

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PYgN/) (using some of the example `dialog` code from the jQuery UI docs, and I haven't included the CSS files, so it doesn't look like a dialog!)